# Какую команду использовать чтобы получить изменения в Git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Я совсем запутался. Есть ветка dev, на ее основе было создано так же две ветки для разных фич: branch1 и branch2. Допустим велась разработка, и человек, работающей с веткой branch1 запросил PR в dev. Его одобрили и теперь в dev все изменения с ветки branch1. Как мне, работающему на ветке branch2 получить эти изменения, при этом не потеряв свои? Использовать git rebase? Или что то еще?

Comment: получить все изменения куда? в branch2, что ли?

Comment: @Эникейщик да. Dev изменилась, как мне теперь получить эти изменения в branch2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107252/how-to-take-latest-changes-from-dev-branch-to-my-current-branch Вкратце: 1. закоммитить свои изменения, 2. скачать текущую версию dev, 3. смержить у себя branch2 и dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `git rebase` для того, чтобы подтянуть изменения из ветки `dev` в вашу ветку `branch2`. Вот как это можно сделать:

```
# Переключитесь на вашу ветку branch2
git checkout branch2

# Выполните rebase относительно ветки dev
git rebase dev
```

Это переместит все коммиты из `branch2`, которых нет в `dev`, на "вершину" ветки `dev`. Если возникнут конфликты во время процесса rebase, Git приостановит процесс и позволит вам их разрешить. После разрешения конфликтов, вы можете продолжить процесс rebase с помощью команды `git rebase --continue`.

Если вы хотите сохранить историю коммитов ветки `branch2` такой, какая она есть (то есть, вы не хотите, чтобы она была "переписана" командой rebase), вы можете использовать `git merge` вместо `git rebase`:

```
# Переключитесь на вашу ветку branch2
git checkout branch2

# Слейте изменения из ветки dev в вашу ветку
git merge dev
```

Это создаст новый коммит в вашей ветке `branch2`, который объединит изменения из `dev` и `branch2`.